# Can't get the algorithm how to update selected row in database ms-access

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access, datagridview

There is a program for hotel. Here is the code of "Arrival" guests:

```
 try
                {

                    string dtparrival = this.dateTimePicker4.Text.ToString();
                    string statusarrival = "Arrival";

                    string strSql = "SELECT * FROM guestreg WHERE g_status = '" + statusarrival + "' AND g_ad = '" + dtparrival + "'";


                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql, connection);
                    connection.Open();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataTable scores = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(scores);
                    arrivaldgv.DataSource = scores;
                    /**************************************************************************/
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns[0].Visible = false;
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["g_totalrate"].Visible = false;
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["u_added"].Visible = false;
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["u_timeadded"].Visible = false;
                    /**************************************************************************/
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["g_name"].HeaderText = "Name";  //1
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["g_surname"].HeaderText = "Surname"; //2
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["g_company"].HeaderText = "Company"; //3
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["g_ad"].HeaderText = "Arrival Day"; //4
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["g_dd"].HeaderText = "Departure Day"; //5
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["g_amountofdays"].HeaderText = "Amount of Days"; //6
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["g_na"].HeaderText = "Number of Adults"; //7
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["g_amountofdays"].HeaderText = "Amount of Days"; //8
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["g_room"].HeaderText = "Room Number"; //9
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["g_rate"].HeaderText = "Rate"; //10
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["g_totalrate"].HeaderText = "Total Rate"; //11
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["g_info"].HeaderText = "Information"; //12
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["u_added"].HeaderText = "User"; //13
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["u_timeadded"].HeaderText = "Time"; //14
                    this.arrivaldgv.Columns["g_status"].HeaderText = "Status"; //15
                    /**************************************************************************/
                    connection.Close();
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please, try again.");
                }
```

There is datagrid view in my application (here is the screenshot)
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruBnr.png)

There is "Check In" button, i want to change the value of "g_status" in database from "Arrival" to "In House". The problem is with SQL command and algorithm of searching the **selected row**.
Here is the code, but it not working: (updated)

```
 private void checkinbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int selectedrowindex = arrivaldgv.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
        DataGridViewRow selectedRow = arrivaldgv.Rows[selectedrowindex];
        string value = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells["g_status"].Value);

        OleDbDataAdapter adapter;
        OleDbCommandBuilder cmdBuilder;
        string checkin = "In House";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string sql = "UPDATE guestreg SET g_status = '" + checkin + "'" + " where ID = '" + value + "';";
        Int32 i;
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection);
            cmdBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
            adapter.Fill(ds);

            for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[2] = checkin;
            }

            adapter.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
            connection.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Data updated ! ");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error:     " + ex);
        }
    }
```

And here is the database structure: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIi1G.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are there any of your columns which contain the unique ID (primary key from database) of the data?

If yes, you can use that:

```
int selectedrowindex = arrivaldgv.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
DataGridViewRow selectedRow = arrivaldgv.Rows[selectedrowindex];  
string value = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells["corresponding column name"].Value);   //maybe the first invisible column?

string sql = "UPDATE guestreg SET g_status = '"+checkin+"'" + " where *name of primary key* = '" + value + "';";
```

Also, here is a simpler way to execute your sql command:

```
private void checkinbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE guestreg SET g_status='In House' where *name of primary key*=@id";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", value);
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Update Success!");
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error:     " + ex);
    }
}
```

Let me know if I have misunderstood anything, or if the syntax is wrong somewhere, since I am not able to test it.

Comment: thank you for your answer. There is ID column in my database, but it is not visible in datagridview. Will chek your code now :)

Comment: @AdilAliyev If its not too much trouble, could you post the code you tried as an update to your question?

Comment: sure, not a problem